# What happens when recreate() is called in onNewIntent()?

Tags: android

I want to start an activity while destroying any of its existing instances.

**For example:**

> if activity A fetches news from server with news id news1000
>    and user calls Activity B from A and 
>    then again calls A from B but this time with news id news2000.

i want the previous instance of A(with id news1000) to brought stack
            top and recreate so as to fetch news with news id news2000

Answer (score 1):

Calling `recreate()` won't pass the new extras to the activity. Try the following:

```
   @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

But, its better if you just update your views with new data instead of recreating the whole activity.